# Python 3.4 Tkinter - not able to give a size to frames in PanedWindow

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, size

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

_root = Tk()

_F_Cassa = PanedWindow(_root, orient = HORIZONTAL)
_F_Cassa.pack(fill = BOTH, expand = True )

_F_Right = Frame(_F_Cassa)
_F_Left = Frame(_F_Cassa)


_F_Cassa.add(_F_Left)
_F_Cassa.add(_F_Right)

_L_NomeS = Button(_F_Left, text = "Sinistra")
_L_NomeS.grid(row = 0, column = 0)


_L_NomeD = Button(_F_Right, text = "Destra")
_L_NomeD.grid(row = 0, column = 0)


_root.mainloop()
```

I'm trying to build an app that consists in a `PanedWindow` widget that holds 2 frames (Left and Right) that are then populated with "standard" widgets like buttons, labels etc...the problem is that I get this result:

[image]

but what I want is something like this:

[image]

I tried to add width and height to the frames, but it didn't worked.

Just so everything is clear: i'm not using widgets from the ttk module, just the normal tk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, you can not change the dimensions of the `Frame` instances directly as you tried because both frames are  `PaneWindow` child widgets.

To resolve your problem, you need to investigate [`paneconfig()`](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/pane-options.html) method like this:

```
_F_Cassa.paneconfig(_F_Left, width = 120, height = 400, sticky = E+W+S+N)
_F_Cassa.paneconfig(_F_Right, width =  200, height = 400, sticky = E+W+S+N)
```

## Full program:

```
from tkinter import *

_root = Tk()
_root.title("BEGUERADJ PaneWindow")

_F_Cassa = PanedWindow(_root, orient = HORIZONTAL)
_F_Cassa.pack(fill = BOTH, expand = True )
"""
Every column and row has a "weight" grid option associated with it, 
which tells it how much it should grow if there is extra room in the 
_F_Cassa to fill. By default, the weight of each column or row is 0, 
meaning don't expand to fill space.
"""
_F_Cassa.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
_F_Cassa.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)

# I set background colors just to highlight the results
_F_Right = Frame(_F_Cassa, bg = "blue")
_F_Left = Frame(_F_Cassa, bg = "yellow")    

_F_Cassa.add(_F_Left)
_F_Cassa.add(_F_Right)

_F_Right.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
_F_Left.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

_L_NomeS = Button(_F_Left, text = "Sinistra")
_L_NomeS.grid(row = 0, column = 0)


_L_NomeD = Button(_F_Right, text = "Destra")
_L_NomeD.grid(row = 0, column = 0)   

# Resize frame widgets:
_F_Cassa.paneconfig(_F_Left, width = 120, height = 400, sticky = E+W+S+N)
_F_Cassa.paneconfig(_F_Right, width =  200, height = 400, sticky = E+W+S+N)


_root.mainloop()
```

## Demo

[image]

Comment: Ok it works, but why you say _F_Cassa.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
_F_Cassa.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight = 1) since Im already using pack on the paned window?

Comment: Yes, always use `grid_rowconfigure()` and `grid_columnconfigure()` IF you use later `sticky` for child widgets for the reason I explained as a long comment in my code. Does this contradict `pack()` layout manager? No, not at all. We have the full right to mix them, and this context is a right one because `pack()` fills `_F_Cassa` within the `_root` **while** `grid()` manager (and thus `grid_rowconfigure()` and `grid_columnconfigure()`) is used to manage the widgets inside/relatively to `_F_Cassa`. @Steve